# How to find the difference between two dates?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Hi Guys i have two date
firstDate = "06/11/2019"
lastDate  = "15/11/2019"

```
var date1 = new Date(firstDate);
var date2 = new Date(lastDate);
var diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
var diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

i get diffDays=NaN. how can i do this. Thanks.

Comment: Because date1 and date2 not parsed.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(date1, date2)`?

Comment: From the related questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript 
You don't use the good date format...

Comment: Just change the date format from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `mm/dd/yyyy` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your *lastDate* is an invalid date.
You can check this with

```
Date.parse("15/11/2019 00:00:00")
```

which will return a NaN

Check the Warnings section
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: Date.parse is not work on lastDate still i get NaN.

Comment: Because your lastDate it is not a valid Date format. Your lastDate has the format: Day/Month/Year (DD/MM/YY) and it should be: Month/Day/Year (MM/DD/YY). My answer is about how to check if you have a valid date format which in your case it is not and that's why your result is NaN. lastDate should be: "11/15/2019 00:00:00"